# Panda help on a particular request

Tags: python, pandas

I apologize for the uninformative title but I need help for a pandas request that I could not resume in a small title.

So I have a dataframe of some orders containing columns for

- `OrderId`
- `ClientId`
- `OrderDate`
- `ReturnQuantity`

I would like to add a boolean column `HasReturnedBefore`, which is `True` only if a customer with the same `ClientId` has made one or more previous order (`OrderDate` inferior), with a `ReturnQuantity` greater than `0`.

I don't how to take that problem, I am not enough familiar with all the subtleties of pandas at the moment.

Comment: you probably need to update the question with a proper title as well as some sample data

Comment: Nicolas: if you are having trouble expressing a problem in a title, it is often the case that your question is too broad. I think that's the case here. Can you modify this to be more specific, if only to prevent it from being placed on hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this is what you need:

```
df.sort_values(by=['ClientId','OrderDate']).assign(HasReturnedBefore = lambda x: (x['ClientId'] == x['ClientId'].shift(1))&(x.groupby('ClientId')['ReturnQuantity'].transform(all)))
```

First you [need to sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by the columns that you use to distinguish records - `ClientId` and `OrderDate` in this case.

Now you can use [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) which used to add new column to dataframe.

In documentation you can see how to use `assign` but in this case what I did was:

1. Check if `ClientID` is the same as the next `ClientID` and
2. Check if the user had had all values of `ReturnQuantity` greater than `0`

The reason why the first occurrence of user with multiple orders is false is because it is treated as if it had no previous purchases (which it didn't) but it could be set to `True` - but it would require additional editing.

Additional functions:

1. [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) - moves all record by the given number of rows
2. [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) - groups the dataframe by desired columns and provided function
3. [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) - merges the `groupby` object with existing dataframe

Comment: I cannot really check if it works or not, but it seems to work! Could you please add the details of how you have constructed the command to help me understand the way pandas works? Thank you

Comment: @NicolasScottoDiPerto Now that I know that this is what you wanted I'll edit with description in couple minutes :)

Comment: zipa: acronyms like "IIUC" are not well understood outside of Anglophone countries, and it may harm readability for those folks who do not have a good standard English. Would you write this out in full? I think that would reduce confusion for such readers.